# Dynamic Input Attribute Issue Checked or Uncheked

Tags: php, html

i am in a table where data fetched from database and process with a loop.

```
<?php $_checked = 'checked'; ?>
<input type="checkbox" "<?php  echo ($_checked); ?>" >
```

is printing `<input type="checkbox" "checked"=">`

but i want to be printed as `<input type="checkbox" checked>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this :

```
<?php
$_checked = 'checked'; ?> 

<input type="checkbox" <?php  echo $_checked ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt see that. His code did exactly what he asked it it to do

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $_checked = 'checked';?> 
<input type="checkbox" checked="<?php  echo ($_checked) ?>" >
```